# power series representation of function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

determine power series representation for the function: $ \frac{1}{{(2-x)}^{2}} $ in powers of x.

this is what I've done: i found out that the derivative of $ \frac{1}{{(2-x)}} $= $ \frac{1}{{(2-x)}^{2}} $, and that the power series representation for  $ \frac{1}{{(2-x)}}  = \frac{1}{2}  *  \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{x}{2})^{n} $ or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x}^{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}$ right? now the question is how do I get the derivative of that series to be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty $$ \frac{n+1}{{2}^{n+2}}{x}^{n} $ (which is the answer to this problem)? or am I going about this problem wrong?

Comment: Sorry to be negative but this question is pretty much unreadable.  You have been using MSE for 8 months, IMHO it's time for you to learn some [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It's really not hard once you get into it.

Comment: ok I did it,I kinda messed up on the not getting the left paranthesis on some of these fractions, idk what went wrong there.

Comment: Thanks, looks much better.  You might like to put some of the more important equations in double dollars, \$\$...\$\$ instead of \$...\$, so that they will be displayed on their own lines.  Good work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the derivative of your series for the integrand to find the series of our original function gives
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^{n+1}}$$
this will be our series representation for our function.

However, notice that at n=0 your calculated series representation contributes a net of 0 to the series, so by replacing n with (n+1) you are just skipping forward 1 step in the series and this is the same as subtracting zero from your original series.

Worded differently,look at the limit as n goes to infinity of both your calculated series representation and the desired series representation and notice that they are exactly the same. So I believe the desired series representation you've asked about is just a more elegant form as opposed to being more correct form. Similar to how

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ is 'supposed' to be written as  $\frac{2\sqrt2}{2}$ even though they are technically equivalent.

tl;dr You went about it exactly right, your answer is exactly the same as the one you are asking about just prettier.

Comment: hmm what do you mean with calculated series representation? if I have done correct $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x}^{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}$ the derivative of that should be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty $$ \frac{n+1}{{2}^{n+2}}{x}^{n} $ and im not seeing how?

Comment: Oh my bad, I typed this up before you edited it to be MathJax, I thought you had mentioned that you calculated the derivative as 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^{n+1}}$$ and this is what I meant by calculated series representation. Do you understand where that calculated series representation came from?

Comment: oh ok I see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the
binomial theorem
$$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}x^n
$$
where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\frac1{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a-k)
$.

In your case,

$\frac{1}{{(2-x)}^{2}}
=\frac14 \frac1{(1-x/2)^2}
=\frac14 (1-x/2)^{-2}
=\frac14 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-2}{n}(-x/2)^n
$
and notice that
$\binom{-2}{n}
=\frac1{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-2-k)
=\frac1{n!}(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2+k)
=\frac1{n!}(-1)^n(n+1)!
=(n+1)(-1)^n
$
so that

$\frac{1}{{(2-x)}^{2}}
=\frac14 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-2}{n}(-x/2)^n
=\frac14 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(-1)^n(-x/2)^n
=\frac14 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(x/2)^n
$.